# How to check if phone number is already registered with custom policies adb2c

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, multi-factor-authentication, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am implementing MFA custom policy with Email or Phone option. I want to restrict user to login if phone number is not registered. In my current implementation it is showing a screen to input new number if it is not registered yet , I wanted to restrict user from adding new mobile if not found.

I tried playing with orchestration steps but not able to find the correct output claim to check if user is already registered or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can’t really check per se, AAD B2C has a built in uniqueness checker if you write to the identifier field - signInNames. You can store the phone number in signInNames.phoneNumber and then your uniqueness check is handled by the policy itself when you try to write the value. That prevents any user enrolling a phone number that already exists on another account.